# Find the equation in spherical coordinates of $x^2 + y^2 – z^2 = 4$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Find the equation in spherical coordinates of $x^2 + y^2 – z^2 = 4$.

$$\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 &= r^2\sin^2(\theta)\\
z^2 &= r^2 \cos(\theta) \\
x^2 + y^2 - z^2&=r^2(\sin^2(\theta) - \cos^2(\theta)) = 4
\end{align}$$
Thus, $$-r^2(\cos(2\theta)) = 4$$

Is this right?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Yep, after you fix a little typo.

Comment: @TreeGaren There are only $2$ variables, so your function is definitely not in $3$ dimensions. You can use $x = p \sin \phi \cos \phi$, $y = p \sin \phi \cos \theta$, and $z = p \cos \theta$ instead.

Comment: Forgot the 2 in $z^2=r^2\cos^2\theta$, but no problem in the answer because the next step is OK.  See also the answers below.

Comment: @TobyMak $\theta$ is allowed to take on any value.  It is not unlike defining the plane $z = 1$ in Cartesian 3 space.  As long as you are clear that this is 3-space, people know you mean a plane and not a single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation given is correct, but we can simplify further.  Multiply by $-\sec 2\theta$ and take the square root to solve for $r$ which is $>0$.  Thus $r=2\sqrt{-\sec(2\theta)}$.

Note that the result appears to be the square root of a negative number ... unless the secant function is negative.  Recalling where the cosine function and thus the secant function is negative, conclude that $\pi/4<\theta<3\pi/4$.  This goes along with the hyperboloid shape you might recognize from the rectangular equation.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 +y^2-z^2=4 \implies \rho ^2-2z^2=4$$

## $$ \implies \rho ^2(1-2\cos ^2 ( \phi ))=4$$

$$\implies \rho ^2(\cos 2( \phi ))=4 \implies \rho ^2=4\sec (2\phi)$$

Comment: Missed a sign, maybe?